# Equatable not detecting the difference between two objects of the same class

Tags: swift, equatable

I have an item of the class Product. I'm changing a variable within the Product class but my addToCart method below treats the item as if no changes have been made. I'm comparing the products based on the id and the variationId. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class Product: Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var variationId: Int
    var quantity: Int
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, variationId: Int, quantity: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.variationId = variationId
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Product, rhs: Product) -> Bool {
        return
            lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.variationId == rhs.variationId
    }
}
```

The user can select a different color for the product and in doing so changes the variationId.

The addItemToCart() method checks if the cartItems array contains this product. If the product exists, the quantity gets increased by 1 otherwise the product is added to the array.

```
var cartItems = [Product]()

func addItemToCart(product: Product) {
    if cartItems.contains(product) {
        let quantity = product.quantity
        product.quantity = quantity + 1
    } else {
        cartItems.append(product)
    }
}
```

The method above keeps updating the quantity regardless if the variationId is different or not.

Comment: have you tried to make the func in an extension? I think that the equatable protocol is inside class declaration it's apply only to the same instance of the class.

Comment: I did actually. Thanks. I found a blog adding Equatable as an extension yet still the same results.

Comment: I would either print or place a breakpoint and debug the product you're adding, because your code is fine, and it seems like your error is elsewhere.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks. I'm printing the variationId of the products inside the array and is not returning all the products therefore it doesn't recognize that the product is there.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the correct object. Your `addItemToCart(product:)` function should be something like this:

```
func addItemToCart(product: Product) {
    if let cartItemIndex = cartItems.firstIndex(of: product) {
        cartItems[cartItemIndex].quantity += product.quantity
    } else {
        cartItems.append(product)
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the quantity is the same if the product is the same? However, according to the first code of the question, you are right, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows, you can also remove the equatable attribute.

```
var cartItems = [Product]()

func addItemToCart(product: Product) {
    if let cardItemIndex = cardItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == product.id && $0.variationId == product.variationId}) {
        cartItems[cardItemIndex].quantity += 1
    } else {
        cardItems.append(product)
    }
}
```